# Load kogito rules file from alternate location

Tags: quarkus, rules, kogito

We would like to have our rules files managed outside of the service source code for our quarkus / kogito project.  Can the be located in a location other than resources, specified by an env or application properties?

Answer (score 0):

there are always one right solution and one simple solution :)

symbolic link can solve issue of place

Answer (score 0):

this is currently not possible. We are considering supporting assets from the classpath (instead of the plain file system) "à la kjar"

source: I am a Kogito dev :-)

Comment: Is this currently possible? Are we able to load the files from a git repo, database or some alternate location? Can we make a custom file loader for example?

Comment: you can add a step to your build, e.g. use or write a custom maven plugin (or a quarkus extension) to do that. You won't be able to do that at runtime though